# How can I have two neural network layers act as the input to one layer?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, neural-networks

When using NetGraph[], I am try to specify the connections between 3 layers like so:

```
NetGraph[{...some layers...},{...{2,3}->4}]
```

But I receive the following error message:

```
"{2,3} is not a valid source for 4."
```

So it seems that Mathematica is having a hard time taking the input of two different layers into a single layer, which is strange to me, as an operation like:

```
...2->{3,4}...
```

Is considered valid, and will create 2 layers with the appropriate weights as output from the layer 2.

Does anyone know how I can have two layers be input to a single layer, while not losing the weighted connections of the first two layers to the third, such as in the following image:
[image]
? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CatenateLayer` for this. Something close to your diagram might be like this:

```
NetGraph[{LinearLayer[4], LinearLayer[4], LinearLayer[4], 
  CatenateLayer[], LinearLayer[3]}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4, 
  4 -> 5}]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I was looking for! There are a lot of layers to look through and understand their functionality.